# Can't use "Handler" approach to adding a URLStreamHandler in AWS Lambda

Tags: java, aws-lambda, classloader

I'm currently trying to add a URLStreamHandler so I can handle URLs with custom protocols. This works fine when run locally. When deployed to AWS Lambda I get:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: baas
```

I'm following the ["Handler" approach to registering the URLStreamHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46619972/28190).

I even went as far as copying the code from `URL.getURLStreamHandler(String)` and added logging into my own code that is run by Lambda:

(Note: this is from the Java 8 source - I realise now that this might not be representative because AWS Lambda uses a Java 11 runtime).

```
URLStreamHandler handler = null;
String packagePrefixList = null;

packagePrefixList
    = java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(
    new sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction(
            "java.protocol.handler.pkgs",""));
if (packagePrefixList != "") {
    packagePrefixList += "|";
}

// REMIND: decide whether to allow the "null" class prefix
// or not.
packagePrefixList += "sun.net.www.protocol";

LOG.debug("packagePrefixList: " + packagePrefixList);

StringTokenizer packagePrefixIter =
    new StringTokenizer(packagePrefixList, "|");

while (handler == null &&
       packagePrefixIter.hasMoreTokens()) {

    String packagePrefix =
      packagePrefixIter.nextToken().trim();
    try {
        String clsName = packagePrefix + "." + "baas" +
          ".Handler";
        Class<?> cls = null;
        LOG.debug("Try " + clsName);
        try {
            cls = Class.forName(clsName);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
            if (cl != null) {
                cls = cl.loadClass(clsName);
            }
        }
        if (cls != null) {
            LOG.debug("Instantiate " + clsName);
            handler  =
              (URLStreamHandler)cls.newInstance();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // any number of exceptions can get thrown here
        LOG.debug(e);
    }
}
```

This prints (in Cloudwatch logs):

```
packagePrefixList: com.elsten.bliss|sun.net.www.protocol (BaasDriver.java:94, thread main)
Try com.elsten.bliss.baas.Handler (BaasDriver.java:108, thread main)
Instantiate com.elsten.bliss.baas.Handler (BaasDriver.java:118, thread main)
com.elsten.bliss.baas.Handler constructor (Handler.java:55, thread main)
```

So, when run from my own code, in Lambda, it works.

However, the very next line of logging:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL is malformed: baas://folder: java.lang.RuntimeException
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL is malformed: baas://folder
    ...
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: baas
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

So it seems odd the same code is failing when run in `URL`. The main difference I can think of is the parent classloader used to load `URL` and my code are different, and so there's some sort of class loading issue.

The [SPI approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56088592/28190) can't be used because [Lambda doesn't extract `META-INF` folders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54061941/28190)!

Answer (score 0):

Initially I thought the old `URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(URLStreamHandlerFactory)` approach was to be avoided, but it turns out this has been improved in recent Java versions, and so I have fallen back to that.

Specifically, a default fallback `URLStreamHandlerFactory` which is capable of handling streams to `http`, `https`, `file` et al is used as a fallback if the custom one provided cannot handle a stream.

This is a workaround though - it would be interesting to know why the class cannot be loaded.

Comment: `cls = Class.forName(clsName);` <- here. Uses the caller's class loader to find the class - which is either the platform class loader or null. You can try to use a `module-info.java` to declare a service, but not sure if AWS Lambda supports that.

Comment: Yeah - but as there appears to be little about how class loading works in Lambda I wasn't sure of how that was behaving. I suggest promoting your comment to an answer so someone can test it.